# Accessing Xively public feed

Tags: xively

I am new to Xively and I am using a free account on Xively. I want to create a simple application to access the public data feed data from Xively, but it seems that I need an API key to access this public feed. Can someone help me to create/get this key?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ratata said is correct. You can access the Xively public feeds with any valid master API key. In fact to read public feeds, all you need is 'read' permissions on the key.

Mouse over 'Web Tools' -> Settings -> Master keys -> Add master key

Comment: im trying to do this too, however, i keep getting the message of please login.  Ive added a master key with only read access, i type in: https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/feed_ID&master_Key When i do so, it asks for authentication. if i press cancel, it says unauthorized. ive also posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711319/how-to-pull-data-from-xively-without-authentication Thanks for your help! @calumb

Answer (score 0):

After you logged in to xively.com.  Go to settings - master keys than you can add master key.

Do not forget to set the permissions for read, write ...