# How to pull data from Xively without authentication?

Tags: android, json, xively

Im trying to pull data from xively.com to my android phone. The problem that i have is that i need to authenticate myself before being able to see the data. However, according the documentation [here](https://personal.xively.com/dev/docs/api/security/public_and_private_feeds/), if the data is public, then everyone should have the access to it. Im trying to see the results of this dummy device: https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1549265960, but i cant without login!

Thanks for all the help i can get!

Answer (score 1):

I found out after some testing, that the proper way of using the key is as the following:

```
https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/FEED_ID?key=API_KEY
```

its really weird that it isnt written anywhere in the xively documentation. All they say is that you can use your key to access data. 
This link [here](https://personal.xively.com/dev/docs/api/security/keys/) helped me figure it out indirectly after some tests.